How to add a monotonic constraint in a GAM model
I use the mgcv package on R, and I have a model like this :
gamm_model <- gam(Y ~ s(X, bs = "ps") + B + C +  s(D, bs = 're') + s(E, bs = 're'),  data = df)
summary(gamm_model)

I would like to add a positive monotonic constraint on X. Is this possible, and if so, how?
I saw that there was a mono.con() function but I don't understand how to use it.
Thanks

There is an example in ?pcls, though it is rather inscrutable (to me).

It might be easier to use the scam package, although it doesn't have as much downstream support as mgcv: but e.g. gratia::draw() does appear to work OK ...
data("sleepstudy", package = "lme4")
library(scam)
model <- scam(Reaction ~ s(Days, bs = "mpi") + s(Subject, bs = "re"),
   data = sleepstudy)

(Not a great fit, but it shows it can be done ...)
From ?smooth.construct.mpi.smooth.spec:

This is a special method function for creating smooths subject to
a monotone increasing constraint which is built by the ‘mgcv’
constructor function for smooth terms, ‘smooth.construct’.  It is
constructed using monotonic P-splines.

